Finding a minimal subcollection of subsets whose union is the whole set
The question goes like this :-

Let $A =\{1,...,100\}$ and $A_1,\cdots,A_m\subseteq A$, such that $|A_i|=4$ $\forall i$, and $|A_i\cap A_j|\leq2$ $\forall i\neq j$. If $m \geq 40425$, show that there are 49 sets among the $A_i$'s such that their union is $A$ but the union of any 48 of them is not $A$.

So, basically we need to find 49 many $A_i$'s such that every element of $A$ is contained in atleast one of these $A_i$'s, but each one of these 49 $A_i$'s contains an element of $A$ which is not contained in any of the 48 other $A_i$'s.
I tried to use the Pigeon Hole Principle to tackle this problem, but I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Consider the collection of all $2$-elements subsets of $A_1,A_2,...,A_m$ respectively. We thus have a collection of $\binom{4}{2}m=6m$ subsets (not necessarily distinct) with two elements of $A$. Note that the number of distinct $2$-element subsets of $A$ is $\binom{100}{2}=4950$. By the pigeonhole principle, there exists $2$ distinct elements $x,y\in A$ that belong to $\lceil \frac{6m}{4950} \rceil \ge \lceil \frac{6(40425)}{4950} \rceil=49$ subsets. Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_{49}$ be $49$ of those subsets. Since $|A_i|=4$ $\forall i$ and $|A_i\cap A_j|\le2$ $\forall i\neq j$, the union of those subsets has $2+(49)(2)=100$ elements, implying that the union is $A$. However, the union of any $48$ subsets among the $49$ has at most $2+(2)(48)=98$ elements, and therefore it is not $A$.
